# Local saved videos don't play again after app closes

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation, avplayer

This is strange, but basically I download and save a video locally, and the store the url path to provide to an `AVPlayer` to play.

This works fine the first time I do it. I download a file, and then I can play it to my hearts content as many times UNTIL I exit the app. When I launch the app a second time, I now get a black screen when I try to play the same exact video using the same exact path.

Because I am using the Simulator I can verify that the videos and pictures indeed very much still exist in the same folder I saved them to, and I can still play them if I click on them from the Finder.

Maybe it's a caching issue? If it matters, I've saved them straight to the `Library` directory as I test this.

Relevant Code:

```
NSString *outputFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video_%@.mp4", guid];
NSString *outputDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tempPath = [outputDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:outputFile];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempPath];
// save the video to the URL
```

Then I "persist" it using an NSString `[fileURL path]` (The way I've built this out, assume the solution requires an `NSString` to `NSURL` conversion).

Later I create an `AVPlayerItem`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:persistedObject.contentURL];
NSLog(@"url: %@", url); // prints a valid location**
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
```

** for example this is a sample url location

```
url: file:///Users/gabriel/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CE1FC933-808C-4003-9BE4-DEC59B787FF7/data/Containers/Data/Application/FAD072B4-B5B0-4487-8A76-57B047324A00/Library/picture_D8DEAFA5-0843-4AA3-BB32-C61E32D13579.mp4
```

It's been suggested I use `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:` and `URLByAppendingPathComponent:` instead, which I will look into. But still confused as to why it would play when I first download it, but not after app exits when it's the same exact file.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code. Be sure to include relevant code for getting the URL to the videos.

Comment: done, let me know if it I'm missing anything helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a classic mistake. You are persisting the full path. But the full path changes. Never persist a full path. Only persist the part of the path relative to the value obtained from `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`.

Given what you are doing, you should only persist the base filename (`outputFile`). Then when the app starts, you rebuild the full path again like you did originally but use the persisted filename to append it to the dynamically obtained path to the application support folder.